# Convert matrix of chars in ascii code with R

Tags: r, matrix, char, ascii

I'm trying to convert my matrix of chars into a matrix of integers (with the ascii code) with R programming. I have tried several ways and I found this way that could work because when I print it, it shows what I want. However it doesn't work :

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 122L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Please help.
This is my code :

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library("gtools")


a <- c('a','t','r','h','f','t','z')
b <- c('v','q','o','h','p','s','z')
mush <- cbind(a,b)

for(i in 1:7){ 
  for(j in 1:2){ 
    data_active[i,j] <- strtoi(asc(toString(mush[i,j])))
    print(strtoi(asc(toString(mush[i,j]))))
  }
}

#res = PCA(data_active, scale.unit = TRUE, ncp = 3, graph = TRUE)
#mush <- read.csv(file = "mushrooms.csv", sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#data_active <- (mush[1:500, 1:23])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `utf8ToInt`

```
mush[] <- sapply(mush, utf8ToInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, we can use

```
library(dplyr) # using devel version
mush <-  mush %>%
            mutate(across(everything(), utf8ToInt))
```

Or in the current version

```
mush <- mush %>%
            mutate_all(utf8ToInt)
```